# Change URL but show different resource

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If none of my `RewriteRule [L]` matches, I want to redirect to a nice url `/you/shall/not/pass`, but show contents of `/index.html`.

This is what I am doing now (this is the very last rule in the file):

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     # is not file
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     # is not directory
RewriteCond     %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}  !=200   # wasn't already redirected
RewriteRule     .*      index.html
```

It works fine, but keeps whatever garbage was written in the URL. I want it to be changed.

Doing this didn't work

```
#RewriteCond same as above
RewriteRule     .*      /you/shall/not/pass [R]
RewriteRule     ^/you/shall/not/pass        index.html
```

I apparentely don't understand how `[R]` works, whether it continues forwarding the changed url to other `RewriteRule`s or not and what page it redirects to when the end of file is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after countless hours I made it work, somehow, I guess...
I am too tired to investigate, but I will get back later and edit if it is wrong.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/you/shall/not/pass # redirects if document does not exist

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /you/shall/not/pass [L,R] # redirects if request URI is empty, skips rest
RewriteRule ^you/shall/not/pass$ /index.html [L] # puts different resource to matched url
```

It's kinda weird that the solution is that short.. How come I didn't try that already?

Comment: Why did you need `RewriteRule ^$`

Comment: @anubhava I don't want `http://domain.com/` at all. I always want to see `http://domain.com/you/shall/not/pass`. The only exception is if a resource exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ErrorDocument 404` with a rewrite rule for this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/you/shall/not/pass
```

Then create a symbolic link like this:

```
/public_html/you/shall/not/pass -> /public_html/index.html
```

Replace `/public_html/` with your `DocumentRoot` path.

Comment: Sadly this does not work. If I comment the RewriteRule, ErrorDocument indeed redirects me to another url, but uncommenting it only shows the new resource without redirection.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think it is briliant! This solves so many problems. I was aware of this functionality, but I haven't thought of using it like that. Wow!

Comment: What it does now is that it displays content of the html file as text. So I tried linking actual file in the directory `.../pass/index.html -> /index.html`, which works, but then the `errdoc.. 404 .../pass` redirects to `.../pass/` <- slash added.

Comment: You can use `ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/you/shall/not/pass/` and link as `/public_html/you/shall/not/pass/index.html -> /public_html/index.html`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but it added the trailing slash.  

I made it work with `ErrorDocument` and `RewriteRule`, so thanks for pushing me the right way a bit. you can see it here `http://nptriton.cqproject.net/game/number/stars`